# R - lmer function for loop

Tags: r

I am really new to this. I'd appreciate some help! The dataframe I have imported is a big table of all my results and I'd really like it to run through each column using the same lmer function.

```
for (i in d[c(6:45)]){
  para = colnames(d[c(6:45)])[i] #para is parameter
  d.lmer <- lmer(get(para) ~ Group*Sex*CS.NCS + (1|Dam), data = d) 
  
  d.anova <- anova(d.lmer)
  
  library(emmeans)
  d.compare <- emmeans(d.lmer, ~ Sex*Group*CS.NCS) # Sex, Group, and CS.NCS are columns too.
  
  d.contrast <- contrast(d.compare, "consec", simple = "each", combine = TRUE, adjust = "mvt")
  
  d.pairs <- pairs(d.compare)

  }
```

However, I keep getting

```
Error in get(para) : object 'NA' not found
```

`para` is indeed just a long strong of NA and I have no idea where it's coming from!

Ideally, I'd like it to write to an excel spreadsheet with this in the for loop, but I also can't figure out how to get the `file=` to use the `d.lmer` function as its name. But that's the next issue to deal with.

```
write.xlsx(d.compare, file = "X.xlsx",
           sheetName = "Compare", append = FALSE)
write.xlsx(d.contrast, file = "X.xlsx", 
           sheetName="Contrast", append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(d.pairs, file = "X.xlsx", 
           sheetName="Pairs", append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(d.anova, file = "X.xlsx", 
           sheetName="anova", append=TRUE)
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question - my understanding of R largely comes from Google.

Thank you!

Edit: I should add, this works fine for this:

```
d.lmer <- lmer(Blood ~ Group*Sex*CS.NCS + (1|Dam), data = d) #Blood is an example parameter/ column header
      
d.anova <- anova(d.lmer)
      
library(emmeans)
d.compare <- emmeans(d.lmer, ~ Sex*Group*CS.NCS) # Sex, Group, and CS.NCS are columns too.
      
d.contrast <- contrast(d.compare, "consec", simple = "each", combine = TRUE, adjust = "mvt")
      
d.pairs <- pairs(d.compare)
```

I just don't want to manually type in every column header.

Comment: Does your dataframe d contains `'NA'`? Maybe you should consider fill them before operating.

Comment: `d.omit <- na.omit(d)
> d.omit` seems to remove all my rows? `d.omit` only has the headers and `d.omit$Rat` (for example) gets me `character(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data, it's tricky to confirm that this answer will be helpful. Yet it seems like your problem has do with how the loop is specified. Currently, your loop is looping over a data frame.

```
x <- d[c(6:45)]
class(x)
```

But it appears you wish to add each column (index 6 to 45) to your regression formula.

To set `para` to a single column name, you could probably adjust the beginning of your code to something like this, where the `para` can be included in a formula:

```
# load libraries
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

# specify that d.pairs is a list
d.pairs <- list()

  for (i in colnames(d[c(6:45)])){ # here you loop over the column names

    para = i #para is parameter # here para is set to the ith column
    
    f <- as.formula(paste(para, paste("Group*Sex*CS.NCS + (1|Dam)", collapse=" * "), sep=" ~ ")) # here you make a formula

    d.lmer <- lmer(f, data = d) # here you use the formula

    d.anova <- anova(d.lmer)
      
    d.compare <- emmeans(d.lmer, ~ Sex*Group*CS.NCS) # Sex, Group, and CS.NCS are columns too.
      
    d.contrast <- contrast(d.compare, "consec", simple = "each", combine = TRUE, adjust = "mvt")
      
    d.pairs[[i]] <- pairs(d.compare) # assign pairs output to ith of d.pairs
  }
```

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful! Follow up: if i look at `d.pairs` (for example) it doesn't tell me what column it belongs to. if i enter `para` it returns the column 10 header. every time. am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect your loop is overwriting each iteration's output. Take a look at my edits. If my code does what I think it should, you'll end up with a ```list``` of the d.pairs outputs. Then index d.pairs to see each pairs by itself.

Comment: thank you! this is perfect! I can't believe I spent so long trying to figure it out...

Comment: In both the OP and answer, I'd really suggest moving the library("emmeans") statement out of the loop. You only need to load a package once.